# Liquibase to use multiple referenceUrls

Tags: liquibase

We are planning to use Liquibase for SQL management for our project(Java/Oracle).

When I am trying to use the diffChangeLog command, liquibase seems to be generating 'drop table SQL' for entities that are not part of the referenceUrl passed.
However this is undesirable, as I have my entities in multiple bundles and generating diffchangeSet for one bundle is dropping tables from my other bundle and vise versa.

Any ideas how to I can configure liquibase to either use multiple referenceUrls or tell liquibase to not drop tables corresponding to my other bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your 'bundles' are all using the same database schema. If you want to have different changesets in different bundles, each will need to use a different schema. On Oracle, username and schema are closely related, so that could be part of the issue. Liquibase only works with a single schema at a time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes they are all using the same database schema. I saw this post (http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/configurable-databasechangelog-table-name) which indicates I could be using liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName system property to map different changesets to the same schema. However, when I tired, that did not seem to work. (Liquibase was even dropping the default changelog table.) Is this not an option anymore for my usecase?

Comment: The property you mentioned is just a way to put the Liquibase tables in a different schema from the one being managed, not a way to have Liquibase manage multiple schemas in a single run. This is something that my company (Datical) is working on solving. The way that we are working on it is more through process and workflow than through changes to Liquibase though.